# The column footer band not to print on last page

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I achieve this? I also tried using "print when expression" with condition

`new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() < $V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue())`

but sadly it does not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

This print when expression works fine for me `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}<$V{PAGE_COUNT}`. It works when applied to either the column footer band or the footer band element (I used static text).

Comment: I'm not sure but it does not work with me, the Page Count return different value.

Comment: As I tried, that expression for paging not work as expected in Print Expression, you may do it on your textfield by using evaluation time as my example here: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11187

Answer (score -1):

Comparing `PAGE_NUMBER` and `PAGE_COUNT` is like comparing apples and oranges.

> [The Built-In Variables](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/variables#The_Built-In_Variables)
>
> - PAGE_NUMBER: At every iteration it contains the number of the pages that compose the report.
> - PAGE_COUNT: Contains the number of record processed in the current page

To answer the question: JasperReports knows a band type "Last Page Footer" ([wiki description](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/report-structure-jaspersoft-studio#Last_Page_Footer)) to define a different footer on the last page.

(Your problem might already be solved. But I stumbled upon this two year old question while having a similar issue and wanted to leave a hint, that one should not compare those variables.)

Comment: This is column footer, not page footer. There is no band for last column footer